# Select id which are there in T1 but not in T2

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables & data as below.

```
create table t1 (id int, name varchar(10));

create table t2 (id int, name varchar(10), t1id int);

insert into t1 values
(1,'value 1'),
(2,'value 2'),
(3,'value 3'),
(4,'value 3');

insert into t2 values
(1,'value 1',1),
(2,'value 2',1),
(3,'value 3',1),
(4,'value 3',2);
```

What I want is list of id from T1 (id) BUT NOT in T2 (t1id).

Output would be

3 , 4 as t1.id (3,4) are not present in T2 (t1id).

### [Raw Data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fdb1/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id
  FROM t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM t2
                    WHERE t2.t1id = t1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why I always get solution after I ask question??

```
select id FROM t1 WHERE id NOT IN (select distinct(t1id) FROM t2);
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee250/1)

Comment: Please try to avoid `IN` when you have many (distinct) records in t2

Comment: @Peter: actually modern DBMS optimize `NOT EXISTS`, `NOT IN` and `LEFT JOIN` solutions in a pretty similar way